# XSD - regular expression /pattern for URLs

Tags: xsd, schema, design-patterns, expression

I  am not very good with regular experessions and need a pattern to only allow URLS that begin with `HTTP://www`.

I have found lots of examples for URLS but they all seem over compliated and I'm sure it should be very simple. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried writing any RegEx at all to solve the problem? Can you post what you've tried so we can help you? Otherwise it feels like we are being asked to do your work for you entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HTTP://www` - they must start with that? ok.  that's your regular expression.  throw case insensitive on it and you're all set.

Things get interesting with regular expressions when you should 'accept' a string that can change.  do you need to allow 'https' ? will you have an authorization section in the url before the domain? (you would know already if you did)   that's when a Regex can get complicated.

## Edit

there could be a better way, but I haven't done this in an XSD in a while.  This will match

```
<xsd:simpleType name="ProdNumType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:pattern value="[hH][tT]{2}[pP]://[wW]{3}.*"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: I want to keep it simple for now, so what you mentioned first would suffice.  What would the syntax for it be?